# How can I add CSS classes to poll questions?

Tags: 6, theming, polls

I want to add some color and formatting to the polls at my site poll  but the problem is that it seems Drupal is not adding any special IDs or classes for this poll.

Then how can I target the poll questions? I want to make their font larger with some background etc. I don't want to change the theme files.

Answer (score 2):

CSS Selectors can do that. You can target HTML that have no Classes or IDs
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html,
http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_descendant.htm,
http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_child.htm

Comment: Won't it be too general to use css unspecific selectors? Isn't there any way to insert an id around the polls?

Comment: Theme your poll. Theme developer https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer is your friend.